# How to get 2 digit hour and minutes from Rails time class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am looking at

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#M000245

how can I get two digit hour and minutes from a time object

Lets say I do

```
t = Time.now

t.hour // this returns 7 I want to get 07 instead of just 7
```

same for

```
t.min //  // this returns 3 I want to get 03 instead of just 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about using [String.format](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) (%) operator? Like this:

```
x = '%02d' % t.hour
puts x               # prints 07 if t.hour equals 7
```

Answer (score 34):

It might be worth looking into [Time#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) if you're wanting to put your times together into a readable string or something like that.

For example,

```
t = Time.now
t.strftime('%H')
  #=> returns a 0-padded string of the hour, like "07"
t.strftime('%M')
  #=> returns a 0-padded string of the minute, like "03"
t.strftime('%H:%M')
  #=> "07:03"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try this!

```
Time.now.to_formatted_s(:time)
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, `to_formatted_s` has actually a shorter alias `to_s`.

```ruby
 Time.now.to_s(:time)
```

Comment: This should now be ` Time.now.to_fs(:time)`

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that you might want the hours for a specific time zone.

If the time zone is already set (either globally or you're in inside a block):

```
Time.current.to_formatted_s(:time)
```

To set the timezone inline:

```
Time.current.in_time_zone(Location.first.time_zone).to_formatted_s(:time)
```